# Swift 5 Migration has Change Circular Images

Tags: image, geometry, swift5

I have a table view controller with many table view sections. In each table view section, there is a table view cell. In each table view cell, there is a content view. In each content view, there is some text and an imageView. The image view is a round profile picture with border. It has always worked. This is the code for each image view:

```
self.imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView1.frame.size.width / 2;
    self.imageView1.clipsToBounds = true;
    self.imageView1.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
    self.imageView1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

I just migrated to Swift 5, and the circles are now square. No coding changes have been made whatsoever. In fact, when I migrated, the changes that it showed that it would make shouldn't have interfered at all with the roundness of the image.

I am at an utter loss as to how to correct it.

Comment: Try to replace `self.imageView1.frame.size.width / 2` with a constant: `self.imageView1.layer.cornerRadius = 50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, nothing suggested here or at Apple developer forums worked. I racked my brain for days...nothing. Finally gave up and decided to just remove it from the next version of the app. While doing this, I decided to try one more thing and it worked. In this line of code:

```
self.imageView1.frame.size.width / 2;
```

I started making the number 2 a smaller number. When I got to 0.6 the image was perfectly round again. I have no idea why everything worked perfectly using 2 before the Swift 5 migration...nothing was chnaged. I am just glad I finally got it to work. Thanks to all for your suggestions.